# how can i use a variable inside a fetch from coinplayer api

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I have a variable `userselectedcrypto[message.author.id];`  (discord.js)
and I want to use that when getting info out of the fetch from coinplayer api `let userdata = data.rates.userselectedcrypto[message.author.id];` <== like this, this however doesnt work, because it looks for something named that in the `data` variable that i get from my fetch... How can I fix this?